# MariaDB Galera cluster filling disk with gcache.page files

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera

I am running 3 node Galera cluster `MariaDB-server-10.3.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64` on CentOS7 and its been 2 years no issue but suddenly recently without any change on node-2/3 disk started filling up and found 100s of `gcache.page` file in `/var/lib/mysql` dir. I have no idea what are these files and from where they are coming i have very small database around 150MB so its not a huge workload.

MariaDB Server version: 10.3.13

```
# ls -ltrh gcache.page*
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 15:41 gcache.page.000000
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 16:07 gcache.page.000001
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 16:34 gcache.page.000002
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 17:00 gcache.page.000003
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 17:27 gcache.page.000004
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 17:54 gcache.page.000005
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 18:21 gcache.page.000006
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 18:47 gcache.page.000007
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 19:14 gcache.page.000008
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 19:41 gcache.page.000009
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 20:08 gcache.page.000010
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 20:35 gcache.page.000011
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 128M Dec  6 21:01 gcache.page.000012
```

Cluster status

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                  |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.804182                                               |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000016                                               |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 9.589450                                               |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 108.139951                                             |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 465                                                    |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 9.869109                                               |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 12                                                     |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                      |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | 9ae87cde-56aa-11ec-a300-0b5af1bc0924                   |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                                |
| wsrep_cluster_weight         | 3                                                      |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                               |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000015                                               |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 8.784350                                               |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                     |
| wsrep_desync_count           | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                        |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                        |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0.000366633/0.000828578/0.00759763/0.000489927/2391    |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                            |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.061330                                               |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 215041117023908                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 3011799                                                |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 4                                                      |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | c69af082-56aa-11ec-9ef9-774d4d1ac647                   |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 172.28.15.79:3306,172.28.15.166:3306,172.28.15.69:3306 |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 228418023                                              |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 904                                                    |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 68793686                                               |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 252                                                    |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 227256285                                              |
| wsrep_local_index            | 1                                                      |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 155.184887                                             |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 43150                                                  |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 1.174518                                               |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 793                                                    |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                      |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                                 |
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | 9ae87cde-56aa-11ec-a300-0b5af1bc0924                   |
| wsrep_open_connections       | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_open_transactions      | 8                                                      |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 9                                                      |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                 |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                      |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 25.3.25(r3836)                                         |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                     |
| wsrep_received               | 6076392                                                |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 1344123461                                             |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 188751021176                                           |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 1400224841                                             |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 16655971888                                            |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                      |
| wsrep_replicated             | 227257215                                              |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 220886044400                                           |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 17                                                     |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
61 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Does it cause because of any cluster partition? which i can't see because i have 3 node in cluster and they are in `Synced`

How do i safely remove these files and prevent them to grow in future?

Comment: This is probably described by [MDEV-19084](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19084) fixed 10.3.25 (related [MDEV-26968](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26968))